# How to do this I want that if a user click on the marked image than reels start playing on other page i have one project in one project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want that if a user click on the marked image than reels start playing on other page i have a reels project in my main main project meaning i have 1 project in 1 project the reels project is made in reacjs and and my main project is made in react typescript for example i user come to my web app and when he/her click on the marked image than the reels start playing in the other page meaning reel project opens and my reels project look like this[image: Reels page] [image]
[image: image of the marked image]..

## MY HOME CODE

```
import { Header } from "../../features/theme/Header";
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../app/hooks";
import { Feed } from "../../features";



export function Home(): JSX.Element {
  const { currentUserImage } = useAppSelector((state) => state.currentUser);

  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Header page="Home" />
      <div className={styles.tweetField}>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>Mowe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>Haewae</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>‎ ‎ ‎  Lveewe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
       <img src={currentUserImage} alt=""/>
          <h1>gy</h1>
        </div>
        <div>

          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Feed />
    </div>
  );

}
```

you all can also see my code and at least pls try this if it didn't work no problem but we will get a way that didn't  works i have tried a href and importing reel project and than add image a onclick but i didn't work pls try one time...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack, Your question is very confusing and hard to understand.
But if I am correct you want to play the reels section after performing some other action on other components. Can you play reels directly? if yes then you can take the help of useEffect and a flag that you can pass from the component you want to change the reel's state.
the code should look something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if(flag===true){
 //starts the reels
 }
},[flag])
```

you can get the flag from the props which are passed from the component you want to invoke.
you can use this code in the reels component.

Comment: i want that if the img is pressed than reels start playing on the page how can i contact you personally

Comment: add onClick event listener on the image tag eg,  <img onClick={()=>setFlag(true)}/> and then you can use the flag variable in the reels section on the useEffect hook

Comment: i dont understand what to do after adding onclick event how can i contact you personally and when i am adding useEffect(()=>{
 if(flag===true){
 //starts the reels
 }
},[flag]) in my home.tsx file than error is coming in  flag